# XML/XSL evaluate() on a DocumentFragment?

Tags: xml, document.evaluate

For whatever reason, if I feed in the source XML, evaluate does it's thing. However, if I transform XML using the stylesheet and it's a DocumentFragment, it goes to the alert("no"). Does anybody have an idea what might be going on? Maybe need to convert the DocumentFragment before running evaluate? But to what? Thank you so much.

```
doc_trans=xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(doc_xml_source, document);

//var resultDoc=doc_xnl_source;
var resultDoc=doc_trans;

//var path = "/catalog/cd/title"
path="/html/body/table//row";

if (resultDoc.evaluate) {
    alert("yes");
    var nodes = rDoc.evaluate(path, resultDoc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
    var result = nodes.iterateNext();
    while (result) {
    alert(result.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        txt += result.childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
        result = nodes.iterateNext();
    } 
    } else {
 alert("no");


var evaluator = new XPathEvaluator();

//DocumentFragment not a valid node type exception thrown here...

var resulty = evaluator.evaluate("//tbody/tr", resultDoc, null, 
XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE);

alert( resulty.snapshotLength);  


    }
```

Comment: "it goes". What is "it" What software are you using? Where is this code running? What language is it written in?

Comment: Hello. Javascript, Chrome browser. Actually working through w3 schools api. Using their "cdcatalog.xml";
and "cdcatalog_client.xsl". I was able to work through the transform but wanted to parse the transformed resultant DocumentFragment. The document.evaluate only seems to take HTML and XML (the old MSXML allowed selectNodes on the transformed XML).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DocumentFragment shares most of the methods with NodeList, so methods like querySelector and querySelectorAll, firstChild etc with the resulting DocumentFragment.

I wanted to find the number of rows in the transformed document (A DocumentFragment) so used querySelector instead of evaluate...

```
var allDivs = resultDoc.querySelectorAll('tr');

alert(allDivs.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `XPathEvaluator.evaluate()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XPathEvaluator/evaluate

Comment: Thanks so much. Please see the edited code above in original post. I tried to add an XPathEvaluator to the "else" but it still doesn't like the DocumentFragment as a node..."Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'XPathEvaluator': The node provided is '#document-fragment', which is not a valid context node type."

Comment: I hadn't come across that restriction or seen it documented. You could navigate to the child element(s) and do the XPath evaluation from there. Or you could install Saxon-JS and get the benefits of XPath 3.1...

Answer (score 0):

I also tried this to convert DocumentFragment (resultDoc) to an HTML element (zz)...

```
var zz=document.createElement("div2");
zz.appendChild(resultDoc);

var evaluator = new XPathEvaluator();

var resulty = evaluator.evaluate("//tbody/tr", zz, null, 
XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE);
```

yielding exception..."TypeError: Cannot read property 'snapshotLength' of undefined"